# Apps script sheets, bring active sheet into view

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks to help from stackoverflow and google+ contributors I now have a working sheet that club members can use to export items in a range of dates from the club calendar into a Google sheets spreadsheet, formatted for printing to PDF and emailing to the other members.

I wanted the script to pop up a dialog so the user could set the range of dates to export, but I couldn't get the new HTML Service to display date pickers (nothing displayed). So I use a form where the newsletter editor can enter the starting monthname and year and the ending ones. I set up a trigger so that when the form response comes in, a script runs, gets the items and formats them in another sheet of the spreadsheet.

But when it is all over, the form response sheet is displayed, not the sheet containing the formatted results.

I have not been able to find out how to bring the results sheet to the front instead of the form responses sheet.

Any ideas?

Here's what I have at the end of my script:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
sheet.activate(); 
sheet.setActiveSelection("A1"); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CalData"); 
sheet.activate(); 
sheet.setActiveSelection("A1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicate variable assignment to the same variable name, (`sheet`).  You *can* re-use a variable name, but don't put 'var' in front of any second assignment to the same variable name.

In my original answer, I suggested using the `activate` method, because you hadn't provided any code.  Now you provided code showing that you've already used the `activate()` method and it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks, Sandy, for the answer, but I have that in the script already, and it doesn't seem to do anything -- the form responses sheet remains in view. Here's what I have at the end of my script:
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    sheet.activate();
    sheet.setActiveSelection("A1");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CalData");
    sheet.activate();
    sheet.setActiveSelection("A1");

Comment: Please add that code to your question.  Use `Logger.log('sheet: ' + sheet)` or use the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints), to make sure that you are actually getting the sheet.  If the name ***Form Responses 1*** is actually ***Form Responses1***, without the space, then you aren't getting the sheet.  It could be something as simple as that.

Comment: why are you activating Form Responses 1 just prior to activating CalData? you should remove - var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1"); sheet.activate(); sheet.setActiveSelection("A1");

Comment: The names of the sheets are correct, so that's not the problem. I got help at google+, using setActiveSheet. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setActiveSheet(Sheet). Bringing a sheet into view is a function of the whole spreadsheet, not of the individual sheet. This works if I run it from the script editor, but not if a user fills in the form. I did find, however, that if I give the users a link to the results sheet instead of to the whole spreadsheet, then the results sheet is displayed at the end. So I have solved this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ScampMichael, I did that to try and poke the system and provoke it into displaying what I wanted, but it had no effect. I found the answer, to use setActiveSheet, as I described in my comment just a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: You can answer your own question.  I'm sure other people will run into the same problem.